# Special enumerated in mathematical proofs

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate

Many mathematical proofs are something like this

> Theorem: the following statements are equivalent:
>
> (1) a
>
> (2) b
>
> (3) c
>
> Proof.
> (1)--> (2) argument
>
> (2)--> (3) argument
>
> (3)--> (1) argument

I can do this manually as follows:

```
\begin{enumerate}[itemindent=50pt]
\item[(1)$\to$ (2)]
\item[(2)$\to$ (3)]
\item[(3)$\to$ (1)]
\end{enumerate}
```

Is there professional way for this purpose?

Comment: Please clarify in which sense you use the word "professional" in the sentence "Is there [a] professional way for this purpose?"

Comment: Defining a counter (\mycounter) by `if-else` in preamble  and calling it by: `\begin{enumerate}[label=\mycounter]`

Answer (score 4):

The following MWE contains a slightly more automated version of your approach using the `enumite` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={(\arabic*) $\to$ \addtocounter{enumi}{1}(\arabic*)}\addtocounter{enumi}{-1}]
\item first item
\item second item
\item[\refstepcounter{enumi}(\number\value{enumi}) $\to$ (1)] last item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ohh. Last item is not good. I think  it can be done by if ... else statments.

Comment: Is there a command that returns last number of a list?

Answer (score 4):

To me, what you call a "special enumeration" looks very much like a candidate for a `description` environment.

[image]

Note that by writing `\ref{item:thmeq:a}` instead of hard-coding the cross-reference as `(1)`, you give yourself some extra flexibility, just in case you decide later on to use `a.`, `b.`, and `c.` instead of `(1)`, `(2)`, and `(3)` to enumerate the items in the theorem.

If you want to typeset the `enumerate` and/or `description` environments more compactly, add either `noitemsep` (for no extra space between the items) or `nosep` (same as `noitemsep`, but also no extra space above and below the entire environment) as an extra option. E.g., `\begin{enumerate}[label=\textup{(\arabic*),nosep}]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} % or: \usepackage[amsthm]{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{enumitem} % for on-the-fly modifications of 'enumerate' and 'description' environments
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:eq}
The following three statements are equivalent.
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textup{(\arabic*)}]
\item a \label{item:thmeq:a}
\item b \label{item:thmeq:b}
\item c \label{item:thmeq:c}
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem \ref{thm:eq}]
The equivalence of the statements is shown as follows.
\begin{description}[font=\mdseries]
\item[$\ref{item:thmeq:a}\Rightarrow\ref{item:thmeq:b}$] argument x   
\item[$\ref{item:thmeq:b}\Rightarrow\ref{item:thmeq:c}$] argument y  
\item[$\ref{item:thmeq:c}\Rightarrow\ref{item:thmeq:a}$] argument z
\end{description}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In general I advise against using lists in proofs, particularly if they are long: the indentation makes for unbalanced pages. Just starting a paragraph with `(1)$\implies$(2)` seems sufficient.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. I actually agree with your comment. We don't know, though, if the OP has any (so far unarticulated) special reasons for wishing to employ an `enumerate` or `description` environment. E.g., maybe the OP likes to have a bit of extra vertical whitespace around the `\item`s.